# Getting the value of the currently bound data using a method

Tags: vue.js

I have this html component

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <button class="btn btn-light" @click.prevent="switchCurrency" :currency="cad">Canadian dollar</button>
    <BR/>
    <small class="btn currency">CAD</small>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the value in currency

```
data() {
        return {
            eur: 'cad'
        };
    },
    methods: {
        switchCurrency: function(e) {
            let ln = e.currentTarget.value('currency');
            alert(ln);
        },
    }
```

but its an error. How can i get the value of the clicked button value that is bound to currency considering i have other currencies listed?.

Comment: `.value('currency')` is not a function/method so this should cause an error. Also, you don't have a value attribute defined on your button so I'm not sure what value you want to convert.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just pass it as a parameter to your `method` like this?

```
<button class="btn btn-light" @click.prevent="switchCurrency('cad')">Canadian dollar</button>
```

Then in your `methods`:

```
switchCurrency: function(currency) {
    alert(currency);
},
```

Comment: Cant do that owing to how i have designed my html.

Comment: @Gandalf can you change the HTML code at all?

Comment: I am afraid not.

Answer (score 0):

This gets the clicked currency provided i initialize a value in data

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      eur: 'eur',
      usd: 'usd',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    switchCurrency: function(e) {
      let ln = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('currency');
      alert(ln);
    },
  }
}
```